# Building a "lecture notes" website with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file-sharing

I wish to build a "lecture notes" website using wordpress.  And would love for any advice on what plugins to use, other considerations to have or website that perform a similar task with WP.

The website should have a form that will allow users to upload their lecture files.  The results should be a new "post".  When submitting the form, the users should be able to tag their subject matter so to allow others to search it.

Comment: How confident are you with PHP? Is this something you could attempt to build yourself, with guidance, or are you really after a plugin to do the graft?

Answer (score 1):

I would search for a "Members" type plugin, that lets you really fine-tune the roles and capabilities of each user type.  Then you can let your users sign up as "contributor" or other lower level, and then use the Posts as your notes pages.  Each post would have the ability to upload a file (not sure what formats are accepted, you might need a doc/pdf type plugin for that).  You could also narrow it down by pre-specifying categories.  Then you could use the comments as a discussion forum for each "lecture".  Depending on the depth of customization you wanted, this could be fairly easy, or extremely complicated. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If the WordPress site is on wordpress.com, then you can set the site so that you can publish via email.  You might create a separate category for each person that is going to post to the site.  There are "shortcodes" (see WordPress Support page "post-by-email" below for a list) which can be added to each email that will direct that post to one or more categories [one category might distinguish the poster, while other categories might group postings by topics, etc.].  Another shortcode can make the posting a "draft" or "private", while I think the default is to make the posting live immediately. *If you post by email, then all posters do not have to have Admin access to the site, they just have to have the unique WP site email posting address.  **If you want to try the "Audio Post" feature (call from any phone and enter unique WP site key code), I don't think there is a way for the caller to direct the audio posts to a category via the call.  An admin would have to add the category to any audio posts later.  ***All WP site "categories" automatically have an RSS feed created for them, so each of your posters would have their own chronological list of postings.

http://en.support.wordpress.com/post-by-email/